# How to get a value of array of objects (pair key-value) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Good time, i have an array of objects like this:

```
var sections = [ {key: 0, label: 'Nothing'}, {key: 11, label: 'Alex Right'},{key: 12, label: 'Dolores Black'},{key: 21, label: 'Bobby Smith'},{key: 26, label: 'Andrew Small'} ];
```

So, for example, i want to get label that is for key=12 (it have to be Dolores Black). If i use something like:

```
alert(sections[11]['label']);
```

this will be wrong, cause it will find 12th element of array, not an element with key=12. So what is th right expression for my case? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
let sections = [ {key: 0, label: 'Nothing'}, {key: 11, label: 'Alex Right'},{key: 12, label: 'Dolores Black'},{key: 21, label: 'Bobby Smith'},{key: 26, label: 'Andrew Small'} ];
let res = sections.find(({key}) => key === 12)?.label;
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the element is *n<sup>th</sup>* in the array, use `sections[n - 1]['label']`; for example, to get `Dolores Black` (the 3rd element), you'd do:

```js
sections[2]['label']; // 3 - 1 = 2
```

If you don't know the position of the element beforehand, you have to give some condition to JavaScript, so that it can find it; in your case, the condition is `item.key === 12`:

```js
sections.find((item) => item.key === 12)['label'];
```

Note that in both cases we assume that the element actually exists in the array (if it doesn't, there will be errors).

Comment: I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The `find()` method which will return the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function

```js
var sections = [ {key: 0, label: 'Nothing'}, {key: 11, label: 'Alex Right'},{key: 12, label: 'Dolores Black'},{key: 21, label: 'Bobby Smith'},{key: 26, label: 'Andrew Small'} ];


var res = sections.find(x => x.key === 12);
console.log(res.label);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap this in a function. Inside function i use the js function find(). If you have more items with the same id then i would use filter instead find.

```js
const sections = [ {key: 0, label: 'Nothing'}, {key: 11, label: 'Alex Right'},{key: 12, label: 'Dolores Black'},{key: 21, label: 'Bobby Smith'},{key: 26, label: 'Andrew Small'} ];

const id = 11;

function getLabel(id) {
  return sections.find(e => e.key === id)['label'];
}
console.log(getLabel(id))
```